# How to implement ng.IDirectiveFactory in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I recently updated my angular.d.ts file in my typescript project. I am now getting a typescript compile error in my Directive definitions. I noticed the following in the updated angular.d.ts file:

```
interface IDirectiveFactory {
    (...args: any[]): IDirective;
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to implement this interface.

I get this compiler error: Type ng.DirectiveFactory requires a call signature, but type "MyDirective" lacks ones.

This is how my directive looks right now (which used to work fine with older angular.d.ts file):

```
class MyDirective{
    constructor() {
        var directive: ng.IDirective = <ng.IDirective>{};
        directive.priority = 0;
        directive.restrict = "E";
        directive.scope = {...};
        directive.template = '<div></div>';
        directive.link = {...}
        return directive;
    }
}
```

And this is where I register the MyDirective class with angular:

```
angular.module("MyModule", [])
        .directive('myDirective', MyDirective);
```

The above compiler error makes perfect sense, but how do I implement the (...args: any[]): IDirective signature) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain your question in more details ? you want a example to how implement directive in ts ?

Comment: Thanks. It has worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The old signature of `directive()` used to be...

```
directive(name: string, directiveFactory: Function): IModule;
```

It is legal for a class to be used as a `Function`. But [this commit](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/commit/3a36795eb258f1797f7ebea8c496201a5ea1436b) changed the signature to:

```
directive(name: string, directiveFactory: IDirectiveFactory): IModule;
```

`IDirectiveFactory` is a function that returns an `IDirective`, so `directive()` no longer accepts a class for the `directiveFactory` argument. Change it to...

```
function MyDirective () : ng.IDirective {
    var directive: ng.IDirective = <ng.IDirective>{};
    directive.priority = 0;
    directive.restrict = "E";
    directive.scope = {};
    directive.template = '<div></div>';
    return directive;
}

angular.module("MyModule", [])
    .directive('myDirective', MyDirective);
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but I came across this problem as well and thought I would share my solution:

```
class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    priority = 0;
    restrict = 'E';
    scope = {...};
    template = '<div></div>';

    link(scope: ng.IScope
        , element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery
        , attributes: IAttributes
        , controller: any
        , transclude: ng.ITranscludeFunction) {
        ...
    }
}

angular.module("MyModule", [])
    .directive('myDirective', () => new MyDirective());
```

I like this solution because it allows you to use the full benefits of a TypeScript class.

**UPDATE**
If you want to use this approach to simplify your link function using private class functions or fields, you will need to define your link function slightly differently:

```
class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    priority = 0;
    restrict = 'E';
    scope = {...};
    template = '<div></div>';

    link = (scope: ng.IScope
        , element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery
        , attributes: IAttributes
        , controller: any
        , transclude: ng.ITranscludeFunction) => {
        ...
    }
}

angular.module("MyModule", [])
    .directive('myDirective', () => new MyDirective());
```

*(note that the link method is here declared as a fat arrow function rather than a class function)*

This is because when Angular wires this up, it does so in a way that doesn't preserve the `this` reference for the class.  By defining it with a fat arrow function, the compiled JavaScript will define the function in a way that will preserve the `this` reference.  Otherwise you will get lots of errors trying to run the code.

Comment: This is a much better solution. Mainly because you can now simplify your link function by putting things into private functions of the class.

Comment: Agreed @mikesigs, although I did discover a small gotcha.  If you want to use private functions from your link() function, you will need to define it a little differently.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow. Such a subtle difference in the code makes that significant of a change in the compiled JS. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: At first I thought your name was Jon Skeet (which was surprising to say the least). :-) Thanks for this, saved me a few hours headache.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamS for the edit, I had forgotten to change the interface from the custom one I defined in a directive had written.  Copy and Paste fail! :)

Comment: What do you do in this solution when you want to insert services into your directive?
In my case I have a constructor in my directive where I declare the services with their respective types. Now when I use this method of instantiating the directive, I would insert the services as strings where I get a clash with the types in the constructor.

Comment: @twittfort I'm pretty sure it would work as you normally do in AngularJS: `.directive('myDirective', ['myService', (myService: MyService) => new MyDirective(myService)]);`

Answer (score 2):

Joe Skeen supplied an answer which was perfectly in line of what I was going for.

There is another guy Aaron Holmes worked out a similar solution to his, which includes some improvements to handling link.

http://blog.aaronholmes.net/writing-angularjs-directives-as-typescript-classes/#comment-2111298002

As opposed to Joe's answer above, instead of referencing ng.IScope directly, if you use an interface, you can define your own scope variables in the TypeScript fashion (intellisense!)

Also moving the logic for link to the constructor seems like a better way of doing it.

```
link = (scope: ng.IScope
    , element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery
    , attributes: IAttributes
    , controller: any
    , transclude: ng.ITranscludeFunction) => {
    ...
}
```

to:

```
link = (scope: IMyScope
    , element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery
    , attributes: IAttributes
    , controller: any
    , transclude: ng.ITranscludeFunction) => {
    ...
}
```

**Here is Aaron's complete example:**

```
module MyModule.Directives  
{
    export interface IMyScope: ng.IScope
    {
        name: string;
    }

    export class MyDirective
    {
        public link: (scope: IMyScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => void;
        public template = '<div>{{name}}</div>';
        public scope = {};

        constructor()
        {
            MyDirective.prototype.link = (scope: IMyScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) =>
            {
                scope.name = 'Aaron';
            };
        }

        public static Factory()
        {
            var directive = () =>
            {
                return new MyDirective();
            };

            directive['$inject'] = [''];

            return directive;
        }
    }
}
```

One pitfall: You need to use a colon ":" instead of a "=" when declaring link if you're moving the link logic to the constructor as above.

Comment: I do like using your own interface instead of `ng.IScope`, in my case I wasn't using anything on $scope so I didn't need a custom interface :) .

Comment: Fair enough! For a beginner like me though it helped me understand how to make my scope vars accessible.

Comment: Why is this new MyDirective Class not inherited from ng.IDirective?

Comment: @Oscar good call, it isn't required but I don't see why not. Will edit when I'm back from vacation.

Comment: Why do the factory if you are not injecting anything? I would do that also, because you might inject something later.. nice